# Spring Batch - Serve multiple requests to a single job one by one

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I have a Spring-batch job **ProductExport**, it may took 10s to complete.

- **Current scenario**:Multiple requests from different clients to the same Job executes concurrently.
- **Expected Scenario**:Execute one by one. Execution of next request starts only after finishing current request. If multiple request are there at same time they should wait in a **queue**.

is there a way to implement this. Thanks in advance

I have tried RabbitMQ for Spring AMQP but it cannot be integrated with Spring Batch in my case.
Bcz my ProductExport API must return a response message(Products will be exported to ..... Email) to FE before completing the batch process.
The result will later mailed to clients Email.

Comment: And why wouldn't that work with RabbitMQ? Send request to queue (hence it will be triggered eventually). Send message that the job has been scheduled, from the controller. Works perfectly with RabbitMQ (or whatever message technology you choose).

Comment: RabbitMQ listener is triggered while a message entering the queue, even if an instance of the job is running. So it will cause running jobs concurrently.
........It will work if the listener is wait until the current instance is finished.

Comment: No it won't, not if you limit the listener side, set the concurrency to 1 and use a single thread for that specific listener. Also make sure that your Spring Batch job isn't configured with an async executor else it will still be fire and forget.

Comment: Thanks Deinum, it worked as expected!.

Answer (score 0):

You can limit threads by configurating ThreadPoolTaskExecutor which will work with this job

```
<bean id="taskExecutor"
          class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor"
          scope="step">
        <property name="corePoolSize" value="1"/>
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="1"/>
    </bean>
```